# How do I trigger a function from a string?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to execute a JavaScript function when I have its name as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string)

I have this function

```
function myfunc() {
  alert('it worked!');
}
```

and this variable which is a string

```
var callback = 'myfunc';
```

How do I trigger the function from that string?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string

Comment: Now I know that posting answers with lmgtfy dot com is prohibited on SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the function is declared globally it will be contained in the `window` object so you can call it using `window[callback]()`.

Globally declared functions are stored in the `window` object so you would be able to reference `myfunc` using `window.myfunc`. As with other properties on JavaScript objects you can use the brace syntax instead of the dot notation which would be `window["myfunc"]` since you have the string `"myfunc"` contained in your `callback` variable you can simply use that instead. Once you have the reference you call it as a function which gives `window[callback]()`.

Comment: But shouldn't it be `window` instead of `Window`?

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing this in browser, try this: `window[callback]()`

It is also possible to use eval — something like `eval(callback + '()')` — but this is **very** inefficient and **not recommended.**

Also, you may want to consider assigning the function itself instead of its name to the callback variable:

```
function myfunc() {...}
var callback = myfunc
...
callback()  # trigger callback
```

This would work in many cases, but of course, sometimes you just need to pass it as a string.

Answer (score 1):

If this is code running on the browser, then `myfun` is a method of the `window` object. You can invoke the method like so:

```
window[callback]();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
window[callback]();
```

And don't be tempted to use `eval()`, never, ever!

Comment: +1 For pointing out *never* to use eval!

Comment: Not to question your reply, but of many people repeating "eval is evil", only a few can actually explain why.

Comment: @thg435: [here](http://bonsaiden.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#core.eval) is a short wrap-up: "Any code that makes use of it is to be questioned in its **workings**, **performance** and **security**"

Comment: Yeah, this is exactly what I'm talking about. "eval should never be used, because... hmm, well, because it should be avoided". ;)

Answer (score 1):

If it's a global function, you can call is as

```
window[callback]();
```

If not, you will probably have to evaluate it.

```
eval(callback + '();');
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the function instead of a string with the name. Then you cann call it via `callback()`